# Unable to use place()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter and am needing to have a object go to certain coordinates and I've tried `place` but it gives me an error:

```
player.place(x=0, y=0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'place'
```

and also all tutorials for the `place` command only cover the use for buttons. So I'm wondering if it's exclusive to `Buttons`.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

tk = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
player = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50)

player.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: You don't need to call `place()` (or `pack()` or `grid()`) on the objects placed on a `Canvas`. Most of them get their placement (i.e. x and y coordinates) when they are created — they're positions / locations aren't managed via the usual widget geometry managers. Here's a little [documentation on them](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas.html).

Comment: `place` can only be used on widgets. Canvas items aren't widgets.

Comment: Use `canvas.moveto(player, x, y)` where `x, y` is the position you want.

Answer (score 1):

`place` can only be used on widgets. Canvas items aren't widgets. Plus, there's no point in using `place` on canvas objects since part of the definition or the canvas object requires the coordinates where the object will be added to the canvas.

Comment: so how would I figure out where a canvas object would go since I can't do it without making it go somewhere I dont want it to with the size parameters

Comment: @hashdankhog: I don't understand the question. For most objects, the first two arguments are the x,y coordinate where the object goes. You're telling it precisely where to go when you create it. It's impossible to create an object on the canvas without giving it coordinates.

Comment: the thing is when I change the first two arguments it changes the size

Comment: @well, yes. The coordinates define both the location and size. Are you wanting to move the object after it has been created?

Comment: @hashdankhog - and when you change the second 2 arguments it will change the size even more: `canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height)`.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry: of course. It's just basic math: for a rectangle the arguments describe opposite corners. I don't quite understand why this is so confusing.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I'm not confused. This poster seems to be, though. I noticed that nobody laid it out in the most obvious possible way, so I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move only the rectangle and not the canvas, you could try something like this:

```
canvas.coords(player,x0,y0,x1,y1)
```

as

```
canvas.coords(player,10,20,50,60)
```